# Django compressor with compass precompiled always regenerate cache files

Tags: django, caching, sass, django-compressor

Why Django Compressor doesn't use cache files ?
In my environement, every time I load a page, new cache files are regenerated.
Even if the sass files didn't change.

My conf:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

# COMPRESS_ENABLED = False
COMPRESS_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'static'))
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'sass --scss --compass {infile} {outfile}'),
)
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter',
]
```